# AdMob not showing my app name! Can I still continue to publish with adMob ids embedded in adviews?

Tags: android, google-play, admob, ads

I have made an app based game in Android studio. I am using ad mob to show banners and interstitial ads in my app. It is in Google play and verything is working fine. Both the ad formats are displaying without issues.

My question is, I have created an app manually in the admob dashboard and have obtained the ad ids which I am using to get ad. It's working. But I am still not able to link it in the admob site since it is not showing my app name (tried searching using both the app and the dev name). I have published my app to [google play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wordpress.indrajithij.brainteaser.free) on `16/08/2015` around 7pm and now it is `18/08/15 10.30am`. With ads displaying without error and at the same time "NOT YET LINKED", Is it ok to circulate my app among the persons I know?
Will their impressions and clicks be counted? When will admob list my new app (I can see my old one).? Also, what is the best refresh ad intervals for both banner and interstitial ads to maximize revenue?

Comment: what do you mean by "(I can see my old one)"

Comment: I meant that i can see my old apps (the ones i published before . like 1 week to 10 days ago). I can see them when i search for them through the LINK YOUR APP option.

Comment: Ok. Then just wait for sometime and your new app will also appear

Answer (score 1):

> But i am still not able to link it in the admob site since it is not
>   showing my app name

As you have published your app on google play, wait for a while, may be a day or two. And then you will be able to see your app in AdMob search. The thing is Play store takes sometime to index app and similarly it some time to show app in searches.

> Will their impressions and clicks be counted?

Yes. Linking your AdMob with app or not linking (until your app apears in AdMob) will have no effect on your payments, clicks etc

Comment: Thanks for you reply. Let me wait some more time then and see what happens.

Comment: Wait. i just logged into my admob account now. still cant see my app. But am seeing Impressions as 33 and Request RPM as $0.04 . These are not from any previous app. This is the first app in which i am using ad mob and it clearly shows that these are the stats for my unlinked app.. So, is it actually counting?

Comment: yes the Impressions and RPM is from your app which have AdMob. Wait for a while if your app doesn't appear then we'll talk. By the way I myself uploaded apps with AdMob and same scenario happened to me

Comment: Tomorrow, i'll be releasing my 1st iOS app. Since I won't be able to "Link You App" With AdMob for a few days, will the impressions/clicks be counted on iOS app as well right away or is it only with PlayStore apps?